# How to add emulator for tablet(7inch,800x480) in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, configuration, android-emulator

Today is my first day with Android.

My need is very specific. I want to develop a application for a 7inch tablet with resolution 800x480.

Though I was able to add Emulator for Samsung Galaxy tab, its resolution is different, that the reason that's not helping me that much.

Can any body please help me.

Comment: For emulator check this link: [http://wisdomitsol.com/Blog/Android/Make-Android-Environment/Setting-Up-Emulator](http://wisdomitsol.com/Blog/Android/Make-Android-Environment/Setting-Up-Emulator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to open Window > AVD Manager, create a New emulator, name it and set the screen size, heap size and android version.

I should add that you should then go to Run > Run Configurations and set your current project to run with the new emulator.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpfull. Adding to this, Now am facing 1 more issue. Currently Screen is like 800 as height, while I want it to be width, or in otherwords I want to rotate the screen.please help.

Comment: Thanks Akhil and Ozzy. I am able to achieve the same.

Answer (score 3):

see yellow color highlighted box to specify target device resolution on avd on time of creation of avd.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

To change orientation you have to use Ctrl + f12